# On a Windows machine, how do you update a file's user access in node.js to everyone or certain user groups

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I am creating an electron app on Windows 10.  It downloads a file and then moves to it to another location on the C drive. When other users sign into the machine they need full permissions to this file.  However, when the other users try to modify this file they get this error:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\xxxx'

I was trying the `chown` methods for `fs`, but all of the documentation seems to be for Unix machines.

How can I change the permissions of the file to Everyone or certain User Groups?